# Можно ли в PHP определить метод класса за пределами класса?

Tags: php, php7

Вроде такого:

```
class MyClass
{
    // здесь объявляю метод
    static public function myFunc();
}

// здесь определяю метод
MyClass::myFunc()
{
    echo 'test';
}
```

Цель, которую я хотел бы достичь - отделить блоки определения методов от блока определения класса. Хотел бы видеть вместо такой картины:

```
class MyClass
{
    protected function myFunc()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
    protected function myFunc2()
    {
        echo 'test2';
    }
    protected function myFunc3()
    {
        echo 'test3';
    }
}
```

вот такую:

```
class MyClass
{
    protected function myFunc();
    protected function myFunc2();
    protected function myFunc3();
}

MyClass::myFunc()
{
   echo 'test';
}

MyClass::myFunc2()
{
   echo 'test2';
}

MyClass::myFunc3()
{
   echo 'test3';
}
```

Comment: Используйте интерфейс

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какую вы цель преследуете, ели учесть ваш комментарий к ответу `Если методов много, и они не маленькие, этот блок становится очень длинным`. Поясните, пожалуйста, [отредактировав](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1061264/edit) вопрос.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, тоже жду пояснений

Comment: Цель, которую я хотел бы достичь - отделить блоки определения методов от блока определения класса. Хотел бы видеть вместо такой картины:

Comment: пояснил в стартовом комментарии

Comment: Если у вас получается слишком большой класс, то его нужно разбивать двумя способами: использовать наследование (ответ ниже), использовать компоненты т. е. делать в классе поля другого класса, которые содержат в себе часть функционала

Comment: А что это вам даст, какие преимущества? Во многих редакторах есть функция сворачивания блоков. Другое дело, если бы вам нужно было динамическое добавление методов. К тому же, если класс очень объемный, то это явно страдает проектирование, в частности, ваш класс слишком много знает.

Comment: Класс большой, но не слишком. Все же предпочитаю несколько блоков поменьше, чем один большой. Уже понял, что ответ на мой вопрос - только обходными путями. Всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Трейты можете использовать на худой конец. Либо описать магические методы `__call`, `__callStatic` как это сделано [здесь](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php), просто к себе его скопируйте и подключайте, будет то, что вы хотите в вопросе.

Comment: Можно еще за пределами добавлять через [runkit_method_add](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.runkit-method-add.php), но `runkit` требуется расширенной поддержки [classkit](https://pecl.php.net/package/classkit), правда, если php скомпилен с флагом `--enable-runkit=classkit`, будут доступны функции и константы, совместимые с `classkit`. Ну или через магию, как советуют выше.

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать либо [абстракцию классов](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) для подобного, либо [интерфейсы](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php). Класс реализующий интерфейс должен реализовать все его методы, иначе получите ошибку. Класс может не реализовывать все методы интерфейса только если он является абстрактным.

**Абстракция**:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    abstract static function myFunc();
}

class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass
{
    protected function myFunc()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

**Интерфейс**:

```
interface MyInterfaceClass
{
    protected function myFunc();
}

class MyClass implements MyInterfaceClass
{
    protected function myFunc()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

Comment: Выходит, что метод все равно нужно помещать внутри блока класса, я как раз хотел избежать этого. Если методов много, и они не маленькие, этот блок становится очень длинным.

Comment: @Александр, другого не надо)

Comment: @Александр, `Если методов много, и они не маленькие, этот блок становится очень длинным`, а зачем делать много методов и тонны кода в одном классе или методе? Делите логику для удобства и все у вас будет в порядке.